# Unit test for redis cache

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, mstest

I am trying to write unit test for below code but not able to

When run it shows the following error message.

> Message:
> Test method DemoService.UnitTest.Common.RedisCacheTests.RemoveAllAsyncTest.WhenTheMethodIsInvoked_ShouldRemoveAllKey threw exception:
> Moq.MockException: IAsyncEnumerable.GetAsyncEnumerator(CancellationToken) invocation failed with mock behavior Strict.
> All invocations on the mock must have a corresponding setup.

C# code

```
var keys = await _redisConnection.GetServer(endPoint)
                    .KeysAsync(pattern: cacheKey.ToString())
                    .ToListAsync();
```

For above code I am trying to mock like below

```
var mockServer = new Mock<IServer>(MockBehavior.Strict);
var mockRedisKey = new Mock<IAsyncEnumerable<RedisKey>>(MockBehavior.Strict);

mockServer.Setup(x => x.KeysAsync(It.IsAny<int>(), It.IsAny<RedisValue>(), It.IsAny<int>(), It.IsAny<long>(), It.IsAny<int>(), It.IsAny<CommandFlags>())).Returns(mockRedisKey.Object);
```

Comment: Your `mockRedisKey` also needs setup for `GetAsyncEnumerator()` since that will be called by `ToListAsync()`.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this can help. This is how I setup KeysAsync() and it works fine. **ToAsyncEnumerable()** is from package below.

dotnet add package **System.Linq.Async** --version 5.1.0

```
    [Fact]
    public async Task Success()
    {
        // Arrange
        var keys = new RedisKey[] { "key1", "key2", "key3", "key4" };

        var mockServer = Mock.Of<IServer>();

        Mock.Get(mockServer).Setup(_ =>
            _.KeysAsync(
                It.IsAny<int>(),
                It.IsAny<RedisValue>(),
                It.IsAny<int>(),
                It.IsAny<long>(),
                It.IsAny<int>(),
                It.IsAny<CommandFlags>())).Returns(keys.ToAsyncEnumerable());

        Mock.Get(_fixture.MockConnectionMultiplexer)
            .Setup(_ => _.GetServer(It.IsAny<EndPoint>(), It.IsAny<object>()))
            .Returns(mockServer);

        // Act
        var result = _fixture.RedisManager.GetAllKeys();

        // Assert
        var resultList = await result.ToListAsync();
        resultList.Count.Should().Be(4);
        resultList.ElementAt(3).Should().Be("key4");
    }
```